# How to enable multiple listeners in kafka cluster

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-security

I have a 3 nodes Kafka cluster. I have enabled `SASL_PLAINTEXT` and it is working fine with Port `6667`. Now I want o enable SSL for different Port in the same cluster. I have enabled the trustore and Keystore certificates. and I did below configuration from the broker side.

```
listeners : SSL://localhost:6668
security.inter.broker.protocol : SSL
ssl.key.password : xxxx
ssl.keystore.location : /root/kafka.server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password   : xxxxx
ssl.truststore.location   : /root/kafka.server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password   : xxxxxx
ssl.keystore.type : JKS
ssl.truststore.type : JKS
```

I Have given permission also. I am getting below errors

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to load SSL keystore /root/kafka.server.keystore.jks of type JKS

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to load SSL keystore /root/kafka.server.keystore.jks of type JKS

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/kafka.server.keystore.jks (Permission denied)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /root/kafka.server.keystore.jks (Permission denied)

The error trace is fairly clear. `/root/kafka.server.keystore.jks` cannot be accessed by the process. Note that the process typically runs on a different user and I suspect that the keystore has been created by a different user.

---

Make sure that the user that is running the process has sufficient access rights for reading `/root/kafka.server.keystore.jks`. One way of achieving this is to change the ownership of the file:

```
sudo chown -R userWhoRunsTheProcess:userGroup /root/kafka.server.keystore.jks
```

Comment: I have given correct permissions its connecting now from the Kafka tool. While doing console producer and consumer I am getting  below error     Connection to node -1 failed authentication due to: SSL handshake failed

Comment: To verify if the server’s Keystore and truststore are set up correctly you can run the following command:
OpenSSL s_client -debug -connect xxxx:6668 -tls1. it's verified.

Comment: I have added below mentioned points in producer.properties file
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.type=JKS
ssl.truststore.location=/opt/ssl/kafka.server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=xxxxxx
ssl.keystore.location=/opt/ssl/kafka.server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=xxxxxx
ssl.key.password=xxxxxx

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the question, listeners takes a list of addresses,

```
listeners : SSL://0.0.0.0:6668,SASL_PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0;6667
```

You already have sasl, so I would suggest using sasl_ssl